# "Missing } inserted" in LaTeX document

Tags: errors, amsmath

I am a LaTeX beginner and have written the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \Bar macro

\begin{document}
The law of large numbers says that if you take samples of larger size from any
population, then the mean of the sampling distribution, $\mu_\Bar{X}$ tends
to get closer and closer to the true population mean, $\mu$. From the Central
Limit Theorem (CLT), we know that as $n$ gets larger and larger, the sample
means follow a normal distribution. The larger $n$ gets, the smaller the standard
deviation of the sampling distribution. (The SD of the sampling population of
$\Bar{X}$ is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$) This means that the sample mean
$\Bar{X}$ must be closer to the population mean $\mu$ as $n$ increases. We
can say that $\mu$ is the value the sample mean approaches as $N\to\infty$.
The CLT illustrates the law of large numbers.
\end{document}
```

However, LaTeX gives me the error `Missing } inserted`. I have tried some stuff but everytime LaTeX gives me this error. Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is nowhere enough information for anyone to be able to answer this, could you include more code please starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. We cannot see over your shoulder to look at your code so you need to help us help you please

Comment: Hi James, thx for your quick reply! I just added the remaining code - it was provided in a template I found on Overleaf. Best, B!

Comment: @Bonobo - I've taken the liberty of making your code "more minimal", in the sense that all material not relevant for the error message has been stripped out.

Comment: Off-topic: Using `\frac` for inline-math expressions is generally suboptimal, from a typographical perspective. For the material at hand, do consider replacing `$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$` with `$\sigma/\sqrt{n}$`.

Comment: Thank you both for your time and help! Really appreciate it, as I embark on this new LaTeX journey - thank you!!

Comment: LaTeX is fun, glad you like it, any issues you encounter don't be shy on here `:)`. Also thanks @Mico for the edit, much better!

Comment: Tip for next time: If you have a long text like this, introduce sone new lines on purpose. Latex will still compile it as before, BUT you can comment out lines until the error disappears. Makes spotting the problem easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error message actually is

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.7 ... of the sampling distribution, $\mu_\Bar{X}
                                                  $ tends to get closer and ...
```

The final two lines tell you that TeX has choked on the item immediately before the line break, i.e., on `$\mu_\Bar{X}`.

You need to wrap the subscript term of `$\mu_\Bar{X}$` in braces: `$\mu_{\Bar{X}}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \Bar macro

\begin{document}
The law of large numbers says that if you take samples of larger size from any
population, then the mean of the sampling distribution, $\mu_{\Bar{X}}$ tends
to get closer and closer to the true population mean, $\mu$. From the Central
Limit Theorem (CLT), we know that as $n$ gets larger and larger, the sample
means follow a normal distribution. The larger $n$ gets, the smaller the standard
deviation of the sampling distribution. (The SD of the sampling population of
$\Bar{X}$ is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$) This means that the sample mean
$\Bar{X}$ must be closer to the population mean $\mu$ as $n$ increases. We
can say that $\mu$ is the value the sample mean approaches as $N\to\infty$.
The CLT illustrates the law of large numbers.
\end{document}
```

Note that I reduced your large amount of code into this small example, you are new so do not worry with this question but it is best to use the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce your error. You can comment out half of your code, see if the error exists then delete it until it is reduced.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of adding the full error message, as it's (for once...) quite informative about what went wrong. Feel free to revert.